# SymmetricDS installation

Tags: centos7, oracle12c, symmetricds

I'm implementing one-way (server to client) replication with SymmetricDS and I'm a bit confused about the configuration to apply to the client node. Should I install SymmetricDS and start the service on the destination server/node?

The servers are CentOS + Oracle 12c database

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should install a SymmetricDs in server mode at the source node and another SymmetricDs in client mode at the destination node. The server node shouldn't be having a registration URL as it is the source of configuration

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to install it. Both server and client have their own properties files, by which the SymmetricDS will configure the server and the client. After installing, start the service. Go to your installation folder and check

```
bin/sym_service install
bin/sym_service start 
bin/sym_service status
```